# Antique Chinese painting

Tags: culture, history, seal

Before I ask I'd like to say how much I admire Chinese culture and art. Hence I always dig in antique shops for something from China. A few years ago I bought these beautiful twin paintings (not prints) and they look at least 100 years old, signed by the same artist. Sadly I cannot connect these painting with an artist and I've done some research. My last bit of hope lies in you, would you be able to help me to translate signature and seal. I will be very very grateful.

[image]

Comment: both the seal and the signature wrote: 李徯. It is the author's name

Comment: Guys!!! Thank you so much, I love you even more :) so the name of the artist is: Li Xi according to google translation, now I am very confused because I can`t find anyone with that name and the painting is at least 150y old,

Comment: Maybe he was not a famous artist

Comment: You're not going to have much luck looking for "Li Xi", because there are some 50 Li and some 50 Xi in Chinese (though your Li is the commonest one for surnames). It will help you more if you look for "李徯". Another hint: "画家" means "painter", and "绘画", "painting". Maybe if you show us what the painting look like, it also could help.

Comment: Also, use @ before the username, so people will be notified of your message. Like that: @joanna.

Answer (score 3):

well the signature is (read top to bottom):

李 (u+674e)：[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=李](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%9D%8E)

徯 (u+5faf)：[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=徯](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BE%AF)

then, the seal is the same (read right to left)

if you goggle, there's a 日本篆刻家協会会報,

www.n-tenkoku.jp/download/vol9.pdf

in page 10, there's the same seal, with info:

李徯　河井荃廬

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/河井せん廬](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B2%B3%E4%BA%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E5%BB%AC)

he's a japanese seal craving artist (篆刻家); so, i guess that this seal "李徯" was made by him. further, it's reasonable guess that the painting is "made-by-japanese".

if you need further info, i would suggest you post the pictures in japanese language stack exchange :)

https://japanese.stackexchange.com

[image]